# ivar scalar and objet to null/nil to release memory in ARC

Tags: automatic-ref-counting

I have the following sequence of class creation : `UIController` instantiates `ServiceClass` which instantiates `DAOManagerClass` which instantiates `DAOCLass`:

```
UIController -> Service -> DAOManager -> DAO
```

If I understood well ARC, when the Service is not used anymore, thanks to ARC, it will be released so as the Service, `DAOManager` and `DAO`.

**Questions :**

1. Is setting the Service to nil the right way to specify that it is not used any more?
2. For performance issue, is it a good things that `DAOManager` sets the `DAO` to nil when the `DAO` has finished its execution, Same for the service which will set the `DAOManager` to nil when `DAOManager` has finished its execution.